# cant get path for mailable inside module laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

my mail is inside a module and i cant get the path to this module right in the mail controller
return $this->view('ContactUs::welcome'); gets me: No hint path defined for [ContactUs].
my welcome mail is inside a module called ContactUs
how to reach ths path /modules/contactus/resources/views/emails/welcome

Comment: What is the exact error message?  What have you tried?  I'm by no means an expert but it looks like you're trying to resolve some scope with the line `$this->view('ContactUs::welcome')` - have you tried removed the quotes on `'ContactUs::welcome'`?

Comment: this is the exact error message: No hint path defined for [ContactUs]
i have tried addLocation and addNamespace but have failed not really sure what im doing though im new to laravel just tried following other threads her but failing miserably